# Zend framework 2 - Dojo_Data

Tags: json, zend-framework2, dojo

In Zend framework 2, is it a way to simply populate a dojoGrid store like Dojo_Data does in zf1 ?

This is the code from my zf1 project that I need to be adapt to zf2 :

myController :

```
public function loaduserAction()
{
    // ... retrieve from db an array of users
    $userList = $dbUser->fetchAll();

    $usrObj= new Zend_Dojo_Data("id_user", $userList);
    $this->view->assign("users", $usrObj->toJson());
}
```

myView :

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.data.QueryReadStore" url="<?= $this->url(array('action'=>'loaduser')); ?>" id="userStore"></div>
```

Thank for you support.

Answer (score 0):

ZF2 has no in-built Dojo-Integration and it appears it is no available as a ZendService_Package either, so you'll have to manually do the JavaScript interaction.